# Dynamically Changing An Audio Path Without Leaving Webpage

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I’m taking a class on Ruby / Ruby on Rails and am now working on a website. I’m trying to setup a page where users can make a voice choice from a drop down menu.  The value associated to the choice is inserted into an audio link, which is dynamically constructed. It then automatically plays the audio clip.  Users can use the menu to switch to a different voice without leaving the page.  What I have below works fine in both Chrome and Safari, but does nothing in Firefox.

My instructor has suggested using JQuery and AJAX, but I’ve been stumped on the AJAX portion.

Any suggestions to improve this, but especially get it working in Firefox would be greatly appreciated.

HTML 1

```
<select name="dropdown" size=1>
<option value="">Select A Voice</option>
<option value="Agnes">Agnes</option>
<option value="Allison">Allison</option>
<option value="Ava">Ava</option>
</select>


Javascript
<script>
$('select[name="dropdown"]').change(function(){
    var thevoice= $(this).val();
    var wordlist = "/" + "<%= c_choice[1] %>.m4a";
    var source =  '/audios/' + thevoice + wordlist;
    var audio = new Audio(source);
    audio.play();
});
</script>
```